# My AirPort Extreme Base Station will not power on. No lights appear. I have tried all the recommended resets.

Tags: airport

I have ensured that the electrical outlet is working properly. I have tried both of various factory resets (soft, hard). No lights. Nothing. Time to hit the Apple Store?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Unless you can test connectivity of the LAN ports to see that it's powering up, but it's not much use if it doesn't boot or let you hook up an ethernet cable and re-configure it.